# Checking for right datatype before inserting the CSV file content into database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm inserting the contents of the CSV file into mysql using the file upload query.

```
CREATE table my_table(
id int primary key,
name varchar(50),
mobile int(12),
);
```

My CSV file content is below:
`1,"John",919898878878,"john@some.com"
2,"Grey",957738378373,"gre@some.com",
3,"Daniel",918786545656,"daniel@some.com"`

I want to check the whether right data is given for the fields before inserting i.e., if it is email it should be in the format of [a-zA-Z0-9]@[some domain] If it is mobile number all the letters should be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import re
with open('m.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        uid = row[0]
        name = row[1]
        mobile = row[2]
        email = row[3]
        if not re.match('^\d{12}$', mobile):
            print("Mobile not match")
            continue
        if not re.match('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$', email):
            print("Email not match")
            continue
    """
        Store into database
    """
```

Maybe try something like this. I just created a regex based on your current info, but mobile number can be different (now it's 12 digit), and email can be different sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`.
The first field is the regular expression you want to validate on and second field is the error message that should be shown in case validation fails.

For email, you can specify as below.

```
 @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$",
         message="{invalid.email}")
 protected String email;
```

You can change the above regular expression as per your needs.
Read more about it here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gkahq/index.html

Comment: Thank you skelwa.

Comment: It is customary here to [accept answers that solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - it will help others searching for answers.